# How to catch error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'subjects' of undefined

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am trying to read a timetable from a DB, but if the Monday is a public holiday I am getting the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'subjects' of undefined`

My JQuery lines that is calling `'subject'` are:

```
var currentsubjectone = timetableday.periods[index].subjects[0],
    currentsubjecttwo = timetableday.periods[index].subjects[1];
```

The function that is being called:
function updateTeacherTimetableClassDetails(timetableday, periodslots, date) {
    var lastmondayfordate = getLastMonday(date);

```
periodslots.each(function(index){

    // Testing
    if (typeof timetableday.periods[index].subjects[0] === undefined ){
        timetableday.periods[index].subjects[0] == '*';
    }
    if (timetableday.periods[index].subjects[1] === undefined ){
        timetableday.periods[index].subjects[1] == '*';
    }
    //testing

    var currentsubjectone = timetableday.periods[index].subjects[0],
        currentsubjecttwo = timetableday.periods[index].subjects[1];

    var lineindentifier = [];
        subjectcode = [];
        roomcode = [];


    if (currentsubjectone != undefined)
    {
        lineindentifier.push(currentsubjectone.lineidentifier);
        subjectcode.push(currentsubjectone.subjectcode);
        roomcode.push(currentsubjectone.roomcode);
    }
    if (currentsubjecttwo != undefined)
    {
        lineindentifier.push(currentsubjecttwo.lineidentifier);
        subjectcode.push(currentsubjecttwo.subjectcode);
        roomcode.push(currentsubjecttwo.roomcode);
    }
    var classdetail = $(this).find('.class-detail');
    classdetail.empty();
    classdetail.append($('<div class="line-identifier">' + lineindentifier.join('<br />') + '</div><div class="subject-code">' + subjectcode.join('<br />') + '</div><div class="room-code">' + roomcode.join('<br />') + '</span></div>'));

    var perioddom = this;
    $(perioddom).find('.attendance-checklist').empty();
    console.log(subjectcode);
    // add in attendance checklist if there is a valid subject
    if (subjectcode.length > 0)
    {
        // attendance checklist might not be available, so we build some code to run when it is
        loadAttendanceChecklistAndRunFunction(g_loginkey, g_selectedteacher.teachercode, g_selectedyear, function() {
            var currentweekchecklist = g_teacherattendancechecklist.weeks[lastmondayfordate.getTime()],
                checklist = undefined;

            if (currentweekchecklist != undefined && currentweekchecklist.days.length > 4)
            {
                checklist = currentweekchecklist.days[date.getDay() - 1];

                if (checklist.checklist[index] == 'Y')
                    updateTeacherTimetableAttendanceChecklist(index + 1, true, perioddom, date);
                else
                    updateTeacherTimetableAttendanceChecklist(index + 1, false, perioddom, date);
            }
            else
            {
                updateTeacherTimetableAttendanceChecklist(index + 1, false, perioddom, date);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

}

When I load the page, it works great when Monday is not a public holiday and there is data, but when Monday is a public holiday, there is no data being sent so therefore it is generating the TypeError

What I have tried: typeof(in the above code) and checking for null.

Any guidance would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Can't do `subjects[0]` when `subjects` is undefined

Comment: So i would need to define a blank array first?

Comment: Perhaps something like: `if(Array.isArray(subjects) && subjects.length)`

Comment: Is that instead of `currentsubjectone != undefined` @charlietfl ?

Comment: No..trying to suggest you need to check what `subjects` is first

Comment: Subjects is an element in the array. `timetableday -> period[index] -> subjects[array]` There can be multiple subjects in the periods for the timetabled day. Subjects is defined as array in another function, I have also tried to define it by `var subjects = []` in the `periodslots` function but no luck. Sorry, I am new to this role and have had to pickup the previous developers work.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question. The error I was getting was being caused not by the jQuery code, but by the XML that was being sent from the server. There was missing data being sent and so the site was trying to read the day tag in the XML as part of the subject.